# Intersecção de 2 arrays com objetos e arrays na propriedade do objeto

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

Resumindo , coloquei em formato de String para poder ilustrar aqui. 
Eu tenho um array da seguinte forma :

```
 "[{"cp_57b326e91ac094817aaf37f2":"1.Folha(Ponto)"}]"
```

E também tenho o seguinte array de objetos

```
"[{"cp_57b326e91ac094817aaf37f2":["1.Folha(Ponto)","2.Relogio"]}]"
```

Eu gostaria de poder fazer uma função para verificar se o primeiro array dá match em alguma opção do segundo array. As chaves são as mesmas, mas no primeiro array terá sempre só uma string como propriedade, e no segundo array, o objeto vai ter um array de strings.

Neste exemplo em questão há intersecção , tentei usar Lodash usando intersectionWith , mas não consegui, imagino que seja pelo fato do segundo array ter um array dentro do obj.

Answer (score 2):

Podes fazer isso assim:

- verifica se todas as entradas da array têm objetos cujas chaves têm o valor incluído na array correspondente no objeto comparado.

```js
const A = [{
  "cp_57b326e91ac094817aaf37f2": "1.Folha(Ponto)"
}];

const B = [{
  "cp_57b326e91ac094817aaf37f2": ["1.Folha(Ponto)", "2.Relogio"]
}];

const includes = (included, arr) => included.every(entry => {
  return Object.keys(entry).every(key => {
    return arr.find(obj => obj[key].includes(entry[key]));
  })
});

console.log(includes(A, B)); // true
```